# How can I get the signature from Vue Signature Pad + Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi I have read but I have not found the answer so I ask:

How can I get the signature picture?

My Vuejs code is this one:

```
 <VueSignaturePad width="100%" height="500px" ref="signaturePad" />
 <div>
     <button @click="save">Guardar</button>
     <button @click="undo">Borrar</button>
 </div>
```

My methods are:

```
undo() {
  this.$refs.signaturePad.undoSignature();
},
save() {
   this.loading = true;
   e.preventDefault();
   let currentObj = this;

   const config = {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
   }

   let formData = new FormData();
            
   formData.append('signature', this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature());

   axios.post('/api/signature/store?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
   .then(function (response) {
      currentObj.success = response.data.success;
   })
 }
```

My Laravel code has this:

```
 $fileName = time().'_'.'signature'.'_'.$this->user->rut.'_'.date('d_m_Y').'.'.$request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();

 $signature = new Signature;
 $signature->rut = $this->user->rut;
 $signature->signature = $fileName;
 $signature->save();

 Storage::disk('dropbox')->putFileAs(
        'signatures/',
        $request->file,
        $fileName
   );
```

The problem is that it displays me an error:

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

So I wonder how can I get the image?

Answer (score 0):

this option worked for me to convert the base64 file to image before sending it

Vue code

```
<div id="app">
    <vueSignature ref="signature" :sigOption="option" :w="'800px'" :h="'400px'" :disabled="disabled"></vueSignature>
    <vueSignature ref="signature1" :sigOption="option"></vueSignature>
    <button @click="save">Save</button>
    <button @click="clear">Clear</button>
    <button @click="handleDisabled">disabled</button>
</div>
```

functions

```
    save(){
        var _this = this;
        var png = _this.$refs.signature.save()
        var block = png.split(";");
        // Get the content type of the image
        var contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];// In this case "image/gif"
        // get the real base64 content of the file
        var realData = block[1].split(",")[1];// In this case "R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM...."

        // Convert it to a blob to upload
        var blob = this.b64toBlob(realData, contentType);
        let data = new FormData()
        data.append('img', blob)
        axios.post(this.url, data).then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data)
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response)
        })
    },
    b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
        return blob;
    },
```

I hope I've helped